# How to hide outside lables in plotly donut chart

Tags: r, charts, plotly

I am working on a Flexdashboard with runtime Shiny where I'm plotting a Donut chart. The slices depend on a certain variable and sometimes are too small for the percentage to be shown inside, in which case the labels are displayed outside the chart like in the image below.

[Donut Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcOfp.png)

is there a way to keep the labels/percentages with big enough slices and get rid of the ones that are on the outside due to smaller slices? the way it looks in the image above is just too messy and I want to be able to see the percentage data without having to hover over it.

this the data and code

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

InT <- data.frame(Category = c(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB),
`Category Value` = c(172928,1106269,222102,0,1054448,682990,1975937,779346,12398,0,1450944,368130,2493154,4347455,1865752,1443840,692972,61891,6443758,1539659,1659183,2711385,856182,1992250,3722195,2762090,257023,1204422))

plot_ly(InT, labels = ~Category, values = ~`Category Value`) %>%
  add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout(title = "",  showlegend = F, 
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Another option is to lump together the Categories with "small" count using `fct_lump_min()` from `forcats` package.
2. Another practical tip: Instead of `InT <- data.frame` use `InT <- as_data_frame` or `tibble` if you want to use `Category Value` as name. Because `data.frame` and `as.data.frame` changes names to `.` separated ones. In case it is intended to use `Category.Value` (which is good) then you have to adapt your further code.
3. Another hint: If you want to use `data.frame` then pass a list of vectors and add `check.names = FALSE` then the variable name will keep as `Category Value`.
   Here are some options:

```
InT <- tibble(
  Category = c(LETTERS, "AA", "AB"),
  `Category Value` = c(172928, 1106269, 222102, 0, 1054448, 682990, 1975937, 779346, 12398, 0, 1450944, 368130, 2493154, 4347455, 1865752, 1443840, 692972, 61891, 6443758, 1539659, 1659183, 2711385, 856182, 1992250, 3722195, 2762090, 257023, 1204422)
)
InT

InT <- as_data_frame(list(
  Category = c(LETTERS, "AA", "AB"),
  `Category Value` = c(172928, 1106269, 222102, 0, 1054448, 682990, 1975937, 779346, 12398, 0, 1450944, 368130, 2493154, 4347455, 1865752, 1443840, 692972, 61891, 6443758, 1539659, 1659183, 2711385, 856182, 1992250, 3722195, 2762090, 257023, 1204422)
))
InT

InT <- data.frame(list(
  Category = c(LETTERS, "AA", "AB"),
  `Category Value` = c(172928, 1106269, 222102, 0, 1054448, 682990, 1975937, 779346, 12398, 0, 1450944, 368130, 2493154, 4347455, 1865752, 1443840, 692972, 61891, 6443758, 1539659, 1659183, 2711385, 856182, 1992250, 3722195, 2762090, 257023, 1204422)
), check.names = FALSE)
InT
```

The lumpted plot:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

InT %>%
  mutate(Category = fct_lump_min(Category, min = 400000, w = `Category Value`)) %>% 
  summarise(`Category Value` = sum(`Category Value`), .by=Category) %>% 
  plot_ly(labels = ~Category, values = ~`Category Value`) %>%
  add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout(title = "", showlegend = F, 
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice and probably my preferred option.

Comment: Perfect, i think this is a better way of cleaning up the plot. thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add a column with the labels to your data and set the label for values below some threshold to NA. These labels could then be added to your chart using the `text=` attribute.

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(scales)

InT <- data.frame(
  Category = c(LETTERS, "AA", "AB"),
  `Category Value` = c(172928, 1106269, 222102, 0, 1054448, 682990, 1975937, 779346, 12398, 0, 1450944, 368130, 2493154, 4347455, 1865752, 1443840, 692972, 61891, 6443758, 1539659, 1659183, 2711385, 856182, 1992250, 3722195, 2762090, 257023, 1204422),
  check.names = FALSE
)

InT <- InT |>
  mutate(
    percent = `Category Value` / sum(`Category Value`),
    text = ifelse(
      percent > .01,
      scales::percent(percent, accuracy = .1),
      NA
    )
  )

xaxis <- yaxis <- list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE)
plot_ly(InT, labels = ~Category, values = ~`Category Value`, text = ~text) %>%
  add_pie(
    hole = 0.6,
    textinfo = "text",
    hoverinfo = "label+value+percent"
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "",
    showlegend = FALSE,
    xaxis = xaxis,
    yaxis = yaxis
  )
```

[image]